# Error after installing Xcode 5.1: Two views in the same hierarchy have the same restoration identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5

I am now getting this error, that did not appear before, when I open my project with Xcode 5.1.

> Two views in the same hierarchy have the same restoration identifier

I tried to change the ids but it's not removing the error. I also tried cleaning my build and deleting my derived data.

Comment: NOTE -- it does not apply ONLY TO the actual UITableViewCell -- for example, I accidentally had a value on sub-elements (just like buttons and so on) -- and that triggers it.   Happy hunting!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by deleting the restoration IDs.

For reference in case anyone else has this problem, select the error to find out which view on the storyboard is causing the problem. Once the view is selected (for me, it was four reusable cells in a UITableView) select the Identity Inspector. It's the third button from the left on the Utilities panel. Delete the restoration ID in the Identity section.

For me, the four cells in the table view had the word "item" in them. I couldn't find any other cells on my storyboard that had a restoration ID. After deleting the text, the error disappeared and everything worked for me.

I also tried changing the IDs to unique values and that removed the error as well.

Comment: It turned out I had duplicated a cell multiple times so I had multiple instances of the same restoration ID.  I just didn't delete it in enough places at first.

Answer (score 2):

**We cannot use same restoration IDs in the storyboard. Earlier it was not a big stuff. But with Xcode 5.1 onwards, Apple is strictly watching this.**

- Check for Same Restoration IDs in the storyboard.Go through all the elements. The error will give you an idea of the element.
- If found two elements with the same restoration id, delete those ids and add unique ones.
- Usually happens when you create an element by duplicating the existing one.